# Automatic container management

Tags: linux, docker, container

I manage around a bunch services which run on different machines. I have been playing around with having this services running inside containers and everything is working great. Next I was wondering if I could have a setup like this:

short term:

1. Have containers to be automatically built from a git repository. So if I wanted to change/update a container I could just update it on git and the container would be updated automatically.
   My understanding is that I could set-up a continuos integration system to monitor git and then update the docker damon through some sort of hook. Is that what people normally do?
2. In case of machine failure have the container management system to start the container on another machine. I had a look at swarm and it seems like they don't have this feature yet: https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/1488
   So again, what do people currently do on this scenario?
3. If all goes as planned (having containers moving around) then I guess I probably need some kind of DNS resolution so connections can be routed to the proper container. How do people do this? Is there a container management system that takes care of that?

long term:

4. Gather statistics about the containers and move then around machines to bin pack everything nicely. Looks like swarm does the bin packing part of the problem, but I have to tell it how much resource an specific container needs: https://docs.docker.com/swarm/scheduler/strategy/ Is there a way to have this to be automatic over time?

Answer (score 0):

for 1, yes, this is quite normal in my experience. we use jenkins for the continuous integration. it has a plugin for building docker images. maven also has plugin to build docker images. i'm pretty sure there should be other CI tools which provide docker integration and also integrate with rest of your environment.